# Deadlock starting c3po connection pool with Zipkin TracingStatementInterceptor

Tags: mysql, c3p0, zipkin

Trying to add Zipkin mysql tracing instrumentation by including the following library in a Spring Boot Application

```
compile group: 'io.zipkin.brave', name: 'brave-instrumentation-mysql', version: '5.6.3'
```

And appending the following to my jdbc connection string:

```
?statementInterceptors=brave.mysql.TracingStatementInterceptor
```

Existing DB connection is using a c3po connection pool configured as follows:

```
<bean id="dataSourceBean" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close" primary="true">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${db.driver}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${db.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${db.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="${db.initial.pool.size}" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="${db.min.pool.size}" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${db.max.pool.size}" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="30" />
    <property name="maxIdleTimeExcessConnections" value="120" />
</bean>
```

but running into issue starting service when attempting to acquire connections from the pool:

```
2019-05-09 22:54:40.752  WARN [api,,,] 31975 --- [-AdminTaskTimer] c.m.v.a.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner     : com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@222a008d -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete Status: 
    Managed Threads: 3
    Active Threads: 3
    Active Tasks: 
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@5cf72aaf
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->z8kflta218cyxuc1srbxxo|30f51f8a]-HelperThread-#0
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@67c13f4f
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->z8kflta218cyxuc1srbxxo|30f51f8a]-HelperThread-#1
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@dff1fcc
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->z8kflta218cyxuc1srbxxo|30f51f8a]-HelperThread-#2
    Pending Tasks: 
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@775717e4
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@1290e9f3
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@7cc597a9
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@9b1e682
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@46963867
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@53dc8e37
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@3f4233a
Pool thread stack traces:
    Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->z8kflta218cyxuc1srbxxo|30f51f8a]-HelperThread-#0,5,main]
        org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:388)
        org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:186)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:353)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
        org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:672)
        brave.sampler.Sampler$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d8298fbe.isSampled(<generated>)
        brave.Tracer.nextContext(Tracer.java:252)
        brave.Tracer.newRootContext(Tracer.java:212)
        brave.Tracer.newTrace(Tracer.java:142)
        brave.Tracer.nextSpan(Tracer.java:436)
        brave.propagation.ThreadLocalSpan.next(ThreadLocalSpan.java:119)
        brave.mysql.TracingStatementInterceptor.preProcess(TracingStatementInterceptor.java:33)
        com.mysql.jdbc.NoSubInterceptorWrapper.preProcess(NoSubInterceptorWrapper.java:71)
        com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.invokeStatementInterceptorsPre(MysqlIO.java:3007)
        com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2671)
        com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2828)
        com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2777)
        com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1651)
        com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.loadServerVariables(ConnectionImpl.java:4215)
        com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:3609)
        com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2550)
        com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2320)
        com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
        com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
        sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
        com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:347)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:175)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:220)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:203)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
    Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->z8kflta218cyxuc1srbxxo|30f51f8a]-HelperThread-#1,5,main]
        org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:388)
        org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:186)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:353)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
        org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:672)
        brave.sampler.Sampler$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d8298fbe.isSampled(<generated>)
        brave.Tracer.nextContext(Tracer.java:252)
        brave.Tracer.newRootContext(Tracer.java:212)
        brave.Tracer.newTrace(Tracer.java:142)
        brave.Tracer.nextSpan(Tracer.java:436)
        brave.propagation.ThreadLocalSpan.next(ThreadLocalSpan.java:119)
        brave.mysql.TracingStatementInterceptor.preProcess(TracingStatementInterceptor.java:33)
        com.mysql.jdbc.NoSubInterceptorWrapper.preProcess(NoSubInterceptorWrapper.java:71)
        com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.invokeStatementInterceptorsPre(MysqlIO.java:3007)
        com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2671)
        com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2828)
        com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2777)
        com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1651)
        com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.loadServerVariables(ConnectionImpl.java:4215)
        com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:3609)
        com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2550)
        com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2320)
        com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
        com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
        sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
        com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:347)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:175)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:220)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:203)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
    Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->z8kflta218cyxuc1srbxxo|30f51f8a]-HelperThread-#2,5,main]
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:204)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:392)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1305)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1144)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$1(AbstractBeanFactory.java:356)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$570/35986993.getObject(Unknown Source)
        org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:389)
        org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:186)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:353)
        org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
        org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:672)
        brave.sampler.Sampler$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d8298fbe.isSampled(<generated>)
        brave.Tracer.nextContext(Tracer.java:252)
        brave.Tracer.newRootContext(Tracer.java:212)
        brave.Tracer.newTrace(Tracer.java:142)
        brave.Tracer.nextSpan(Tracer.java:436)
        brave.propagation.ThreadLocalSpan.next(ThreadLocalSpan.java:119)
        brave.mysql.TracingStatementInterceptor.preProcess(TracingStatementInterceptor.java:33)
        com.mysql.jdbc.NoSubInterceptorWrapper.preProcess(NoSubInterceptorWrapper.java:71)
        com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.invokeStatementInterceptorsPre(MysqlIO.java:3007)
        com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2671)
        com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2828)
        com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2777)
        com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1651)
        com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.loadServerVariables(ConnectionImpl.java:4215)
        com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:3609)
        com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2550)
        com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2320)
        com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
        com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
        sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
        com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:347)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:175)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:220)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:206)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:203)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the trace is triggering an old-fashioned inverted-lock-order deadlock freezing threads that are attempting to acquire new Connections.

The last of the three deadlocked threads is [trying to get a lock on some singleton or bean](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java#L204). It has already passed through and presumably acquired a lock on a `GenericScope`.

The other two threads are [trying to acquire a lock on a `GenericScope`](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/master/spring-cloud-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/context/scope/GenericScope.java#L387-L388), which presumably the first thread has.

An unexpected reentrance from the `zipkin` code into spring is generating a deadlock. `c3p0` has a fixed-size thread pool that notices when all its threads (just 3 here, `c3p0`'s default) are persistently frozen, then (pretty correctly in this case) declares a deadlock and replaces the blocked threads in hopes of recovering.

Does c3p0 recover? Is this a rare or frequent deadlock? There's not much you can easily do to prevent this deadlock, I think either you'll have to tolerate it or do without the instrumentation.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @stevewaldman. No c3po does not recover and this happens consistently on startup. I will look into some other options or go without this instrumentation.

Comment: Interesting, this is caused because the brave Sampler is a bean which has not been created yet but the Tracer has. I believe if you mark your datasource as depends-on all the tracing beans, or the other way around you can avoid this deadlock

Comment: (my fatalism was perhaps misplaced! if @BrianDevins solution works, feel free to unaccept and encourage him to pull his comment into an answer.)

Comment: Explicitly setting the sampler as a dependency of the connection pool worked a treat and I now have my app working with the Zipkin mysql instrumentation. Thanks for all your help guys. @BrianDevins please add this as an Answer and I will update this to accepted.

Comment: i hope @BrianDevins turns his comment into an answer, and that you transfer the green chackmark to him!